# background CSS с линейными цветными радиусами

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, linear-gradient

Дизайнер придумал этот тип фона, как показано на изображении ниже.
Я бы не хотел использовать фоновые изображения.
Итак, я пытаюсь понять, можно ли воспроизвести это с помощью атрибута background CSS.

Самый нижний слой - это просто линейный градиент, там никаких проблем. Но круглые формы, которые накладываются поверх этого, не так просты (если это вообще возможно).

Моя первая мысль заключалась в том, чтобы использовать различные радиальные градиенты для круглых форм, но, как вы можете видеть, эти формы имеют линейную заливку и нуждаются в прозрачном фоне, чтобы круг постепенно исчезал. Я не вижу способа добиться этого, но я не эксперт по CSS, поэтому хотел бы услышать некоторые мнения по этому поводу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [CSS background with linear colored radials](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68733253/7394871) от участника  [@Solide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973685/solide).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68733253/7394871

Answer (score 2):

маска может помочь вам приблизиться к этому результату:

```css
.box {
  height:500px;
  background:linear-gradient(135deg,#001f8e,#00fdcf);
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset:0;
  background:linear-gradient(#00fdcf,#001f8e);
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(circle 120px,#000 75%,#0000);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Или базовый округлый элемент с фильтром размытия:

```css
.box {
  height:500px;
  background:linear-gradient(135deg,#001f8e,#00fdcf);
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset:calc(50% - 100px) calc(50% - 100px);
  background:linear-gradient(#00fdcf,#001f8e);
  border-radius:50%;
  filter:blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68733482/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>